# What would be the equivalent of Application_EndRequest (ASP.NET) in Java Tomcat?

Tags: c#, java, tomcat, iis-7

I saw this code snippet about post logging:
https://serverfault.com/questions/90943/iis-log-request-body-post-data

which uses Application_EndRequest. Need to do the same in Java /Tomcat. Still will it work ? Because in IIS7 the request is passed along to app request handlers but in Tomcat I fear that the request parameters disappears if it is already pre-processed.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) to do the logging you're looking for; it also looks like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) has a configuration option to log requests, although I don't know if it goes into details such as post parameters.

Comment: A Filter is definitely the best way to do this, and will work across all containers, not just for Tomcat. 

AFAIK, there is no way to log post parameters via configuration of the standard Tomcat logging.

Comment: Yes but as I said there is problem that parameters would be eaten by that filter when it arrives at your app handler.